# .css file doesn't get carried out

Tags: php, .htaccess

Style.css doesn't get carried out when url is `http://example.com/mvc/login/requestsExceeded`,

but it does in my login index page that is `http://example.com/mvc/login`,

if I add forward slash `http://example.com/mvc/login/`, then it doesn't work either.

> mvc = site in subdirectory
>   login = controller
>   requestsExceeded = view

.css file is in `http://www.example.com/mvc/views/themes/default/style.css`

The file path is ok becouse i've tryed like this:

```
<?php if(file_exists("views/themes/{$theme}/style.css")) echo 'TEST'; ?>
<link href="views/themes/<?=$theme;?>/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

and it does echo out TEST.

Here my simplified router:

```
<?php

$controller = "Index";
$action = "index";
$query = null;

if (isset($_GET['load']))
{
    $params = array();
    $params = explode("/", $_GET['load']);

    $controller = ucwords($params[0]);

    if (isset($params[1]) && !empty($params[1]))
    {
        $action = $params[1];
    }

    if (isset($params[2]) && !empty($params[2]))
    {
        $query = $params[2];
    }
}
$modelName = $controller;
$controller .= 'Controller';

$load = new $controller($modelName, $action);

if (method_exists($load, $action))
{
    $load->{$action}($query);
}
else 
{
    die('Invalid method. Please check the URL.');
}
```

I'm pretty sure that this is caused by .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?load=$1 [PT,L]
```

-I would like to restrict all access unless index.php...,
-Allow access to .css,.gz,.js and image files,
-remove the forward slash from url,
-redirect 301 to index.php,
-redirect `http://example.com/mvc/home` to index.php,

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your import to

```
<link href="/mvc/views/themes/<?=$theme;?>/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

If you want the same link to work from anywhere in your site, then you'd better let the path be absolute, that is start with `/`.

Comment: If I ad '/' then images are shown, but no design is applied and it breaks my javascript for navigation. Why's that?

Comment: @troks I didn't add just `/` but also `mvc`.

Comment: Ups:) it works now. thx! Just some short question: >link< tag is just for .css files?

Comment: Not only css files, see [the MDN on link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTML/Element/link). But that's the most common use by far.